# Functional derivative in $n$- dimensions using vector calculus

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-fields

Let F(g(f))
be a functional that sends functions of a vector variable ( from n
-dimensional vector space) to R.

g
is some function of scalar valued functions f
.

It can be shown using vector calculus that the first (order) functional derivative $\partial F$
is equal to the partial derivative of g
with respect to f
minus the divergence of the gradient of g
.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative

$F=\int f ^{4} dx^{4}$

$\partial F= \frac{\partial{g}}{\partial{f}} - \nabla \cdot\nabla g(f)$

Divergence of the gradient should be equal to 4 , and if I plug in the above functional into the formula on wiki it should work just as well for 4d and I get the result :$ \partial F=−12f^{3}$

Can I just plug this into the formula again and get the second derivative of the functional?

Comment: Usage of LaTex is highly recommended.

Comment: If someone could tex it up id appreciate it , I'm only with my phone now .